# Check if a row in column is unique python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

```py
| id1      | result         |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2        |         0.5    |
| 3        |         1.4    |
| 4        |         1.4    |
| 7        |         3.4    |
| 2        |         1.4    |
```

I want to check for every row in the column ['id1'] if the value is unique

The output should be:

```py
False
True
True
True
False
```

The first and the last are False because id 2 exists twice.

I used this method:

```py
bool = df["id1"].is_unique`
```

but that checks if the whole column is unique. I want to check it for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
df['id1'].map(~(df.groupby('id1').size() > 1))
```

###### Output

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: id1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I saw you tagged this question with pandas, I'm assuming you're using the pandas package.
You can create an array with a bunch of id1 here, then use `pd.Series.duplicated` method like the following example.
You can get the pandas docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html#pandas-index-duplicated).

```python
import pandas as pd
check_id1_duplicate = pd.Index([2, 3, 4, 7, 2])
check_id1_duplicate.duplicated(keep=False)
# Results would be array([True, False, False, False, True])
```

Comment: Yes it is a pandas DataFrame already. I love your solution, it can be modified to one liner: `~df['id1'].duplicated(keep=False)`. Mind the desired output in question.

Comment: Sorry for didn't notice that data frame part and desired output

Comment: No problem. I was not aware of [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), happy to learn something new today 

Comment: The `duplicated` solution seems much more intuitive compared to the `size() > 1` check in the accepted answer. I suspect it'd be much faster too.

Comment: @npetrov937 indeed it is much faster. The result is a bit different though from what was accepted as mentioned here in the comments. Guess that's why it was not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ShiriNmi's answer, the `duplicated` solution is more intuitive and about 8 times faster, while returning the same result.

```py
%timeit -n 10_000 df['id1'].map(~(df.groupby('id1').size() > 1))
# 697 µs ± 60.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit ~df['id1'].duplicated(keep=False)
# 89.5 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```